# Does an exact $(p,q)$-form on a non-compact Kähler manifold admit a primitive with at least $p$ $dz$'s?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

**Motivation**: On a compact Kähler manifold $Y$, $\partial\bar{\partial}$-lemma tells us that an exact $(p,q)$-form $\omega$ has a primitive $\eta$ with $p$ $dz$'s, namely $\eta\in F^p\mathcal{A}^{p+q-1}_Y$. Here $\eta$ is a primitive of $\omega$ means $d\eta=\omega$. This is because $\omega=\bar{\partial}\partial\sigma$ for some $\sigma$ of type $(p-1,q-1)$, so we can just take $\eta=\partial\sigma$.

I'm looking for something similar for a non-compact Kähler manifold. However, we don't have $\partial\bar{\partial}$-lemma anymore.

The case I'm interested in is when $X$ is the total space of a smooth family $\pi:X\to \Delta$ of compact Kähler manifolds, where $\Delta$ is a holomorphic disk. Let $\omega$ be an exact smooth form of type $(p,q)$. Let $X_0=\pi^{-1}(0)$. I'd like to know

**Question**: *Is there a smooth form $\eta$ such that $d\eta=\omega$ and $\eta_{\rvert X_0}\in F^p\mathcal{A}_{X_0}^{p+q-1}$?*

I'm not sure if similar questions were considered. I would appreciate it if someone could provide a reference or share some ideas.